# Add Window to Panel/Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add another WPF window to panel or grid? In C# there was a problem. I know that UserControl solve my problem, but will not border with Minimizing, Maximizing, Closing.

I would like to have this effect:

[image: Effect I Would Like to Achieve]

How can I do this?

Comment: You're trying to build a Multi Document Interface (MDI). In times of Single Window Interfaces, this is **not best practice**, as it's likely to distract the user: There are *real* windows (your application window) and *kind-of* windows (in your application). This is last century design and should be avoided. If you still want to do something like this in WPF, please look into https://wpfmdi.codeplex.com for some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but if this is not best practice, what are best practice in wpf now? That the interface was nice and good for users?

Comment: They have an own Stack Exchange site for user experience. You could take this one into consideration: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45223/which-one-is-better-in-our-case-if-mdi-is-considered-bad